# I can't run instrument in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

Im new to instrument and ios development. I have this app and I want to test it in instrument to see how this is set inside my app but I can't run any of instrument in my machine whenever I choose one here [image]

it directs me to this

[image]

then when I choose one, this alert pop up

[image]

could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run this command from a term:

```
sudo chmod a+rwxt /Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.instruments
```

Take a look at ["Unable to Profile as *.tracetemplate "could not be opened."](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6441)

Answer (score 0):

Your Xcode installation looks corrupted. Uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode should fix your issue.

Comment: you think so sir? because it will take a while if i reinstall the xcode